# Timing getting off in Serial communications

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port

I have a WPF application that runs a RS232 serial communication that I am writting to replace an old (baldly written) Borland C++ dos executable.

In my application to keep the UI separate from the communications I run the serial on it's own thread. I send messages to the attached device every 30ms. I have set up a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler to capture any received messages.

```
    public override void DataRecieved()
    {
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting());
    }
```

In the received handler I queue the received messages and do what I want with them in another thread.

My problem is when I put a scope on the serial communications lines I see most of my packets are going out at 30ms intervals but some at 40ms. The received messages do not line up with these out messages at 40ms.

I am using a System.Timers.Timer for my time interval set to 30ms and only send three bytes on the ElapsedEventHandler.

```
        // Initialize and Start timer
        timer = new Timer(30);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Start();


    private void Timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            // Write
            byte[] _buffer = { byte1};
            WriteBuffer(_buffer);


            // Write
            byte[] _buffer1 = { byte2 };
            WriteBuffer(_buffer1);


            // Write
            byte[] _buffer2 = { byte3};
            WriteBuffer(_buffer2);
        }
    }
```

Is there something in System.Timers.Timer that would miss a 30ms interval and go longer?
Should I be using a different timer all together?

Comment: A System.Timers.Timer's delivery time is not guaranteed. This is true for any timer on Windows, btw, and especially in a .NET app where you have things like garbage collection. Why is the timing a problem?

Comment: Windows is a co-operative multitasking environment.  There are times when Windows or another app is simply busy doing something and can't schedule time for another app.  This is something you have to be able to deal with in Windows because it is not a real-time OS.

Comment: I talked to my coworker about this too and he said the same thing about Windows not being a real-time OS. It is a bummer that none of the timers are a true absolute timer.I need the timer to be a precise as possible for the device it is connected to is looking for communications within60ms and30ms is ideal.The reason I worried about the40ms is I have a faster computer than some of the computers it will end up on,and I didn't know if the 40ms would be worse on them if this was something beyond Windows being backed up.I tried a delay instead of a timer and I get less40ms issues,going with that.

Comment: This is well on its way to be a baldly written WPF app.  It doesn't have anything to do with a "fast" machine, everything with how well-behaved the installed drivers are.  Which is a problem on any consumer grade machine, video and audio drivers in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am using StopWatch with the Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds Property. When ever my Elapsed time is greater or equal to 30ms I send my messages.

```
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        while (!Stopped)
        {
            // Loop here. 
            // Received Event handler is capturing messages.

            // Wait 30ms between commands
            if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 33)
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    // Write 
                    byte[] _buffer = { byte1, byte2, byte2 };
                    WriteBuffer(_buffer);
                }

                stopWatch.Reset();
                stopWatch.Start();
            }
        }
```

When I had the timer it was

```
while (!Stopped)
{
     // Loop here. 
     // Received Event handler is capturing messages.
     // Timer is sending messages
}
```

The reason this works over a Timer or a delay (System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30)) is I was giving up my thread to the Windows Event Handler. Meaning I was waiting for Windows to tell me it was okay to proceed. I didn't have control over my thread.

Now using the StopWatch isn't perfect, but it is way closer than the Timer, some 32-33ms

Thank you - @500 - Internal Server Error, @Peter Ritchie, and my coworkers